# DateTime.ParseExact() is producing anomalous results. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: c#, datetime

Just wondering if anyone could tell me why in this line of code (below), the ParseExact function is returning a seemingly random date out of nowhere instead of the actual date in the input string?

```
            foreach (Car c in cars)
        {
            Car obj = new Car();
            obj.CarID = c.CarID;
            obj.Reg = c.Reg;
            obj.Make = c.Make;
            obj.Model = c.Model;
            obj.Mileage = c.Mileage;
            if(c.LastInspection != null && c.LastInspection != "N/A")
            {
                obj.LastInspectionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(c.LastInspection, "yyyy'/'mm'/'dd", null);
            }
            obj.StaffID = c.StaffID;
            obj.OfficeID = c.OfficeID;
            carsDate.Add(obj);
        }

        return carsDate;
```

In one of my records, 'c.LastInspection' = "2013/06/08", but for some reason every time I parse said string using the above code, 'obj.LastInspectionDate' gets changed to "Tuesday 08/01/2013 00:06:00". Now the day and time don't bother me as I'm only using it to store the date, but, quite obviously, it's the wrong date! Ran through the code a bunch of times and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `mm` to `MM` in your format string.

`mm` is: *The minute, from 00 through 59.*

`MM` is: *The month, from 01 through 12.*

Check a list of [custom data and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.

Because you used `mm` `06` from your input string is taken as minutes. And because there is no Month specified `1` is taken as default.

Comment: ...because "mm" is Minutes and "MM" is months.

Comment: Wow. Yeah that sorted it, feel like an idiot now lol. Thanks :D